# In kotlin, how to filter a list after using the map

Tags: kotlin

How I filter a list by an list of id, after a map? I get an object list with findAll, use map to send a list, but I need show the list only some ids eg: (1,2,5,7). I don't know what to put inside the filter for it to bring the filtered map the way I need it

```
@Service
class RecommendationService(val reasonRepository: ReasonRepository) {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    fun getLoanAndReasonDecision(loanAmount: Int): ReasonResponse {
        val list = reasonRepository.findAll()
        return if (loanAmount <= LOAN_LOW) {
            ReasonResponse(LOW)
        } else if (loanAmount in LOAN_MEDIUM_FIRST_PARAMETER..LOAN_MEDIUM_SECOND_PARAMETER) {
            ReasonResponse(MEDIUM, (
                list.map { it.toDto()}.filter { it ->  }
            ))
        } else ReasonResponse(HIGH, ((
                list.map { it.toDto() }
        )))
    }
}
```

Comment: `I need show the list only some ids eg: (1,2,5,7)` What are those ids? Where are you getting these from?

Comment: some example id of object that my findAll return

Comment: What does the class returned to `it.toDto()` contain?

Comment: And what do you expect to happen if `loanAmount > LOAN_LOW` but less than `LOAN_MEDIUM_FIRST_PARAMETER`?

Comment: It.toDto() return dto of my objects and theses const have int value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains()` to check if a value is present in a list of values.

Assuming that the objects of your list have the parameter `id` and that those ids you want to filter are always going to be the same, you can achieve what you describe like following:

```
list.map { it.toDto()}.filter { listOf(1,2,5,7).contains(it.id)}
```

Comment: This error occurs in the contains method: Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.

Comment: What type does `it.id` have?

Comment: If your id is a string then you must compare against strings. `filter { listOf("1","2","5","7").contains(it.id)}` In this scenario i assumed your id is a number because you didn't provide any detail in your question.

Comment: my id is type Long

Comment: You can also do `filter { it.id in ids }` if you like (assuming ``ids`` is your list of valid IDs you've defined/passed in somewhere)

Comment: I received the same error : Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.

Comment: Are you sure the error is related to the filtering code?